# sencha mac working directory is not recognized

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I downloaded and installed Sencha Touch on my Mac (http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/sencha-touch-2.1/). 
Whenever I type sencha command in terminal I am getting the:

```
[WARN] The current working directory (/Users/jmc72) is not a recognized Sencha SDK or application folder. Running in backwards compatible mode.
```

I tried to run it from different directories and output is the same.

My PATH looks like:

```
/Applications/SenchaSDKTools:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/Applications/SenchaSDKTools:
/Users/jmc72/Sites/senchaSDK:
/usr/X11/bin
```

My .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools:$PATH

export PATH=/Users/jmc72/Sites/senchaSDK:$PATH
```

Sencha SDK (documentation ?) is located in /Users/jmc72/Sites/senchaSDK 
and SDKTools are located in /Applications/SenchaSDKTools

EDIT
Following the suggestion I created the .senchsdk file but now I am getting the following error:

```
sencha

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/sadmin/Downloads/sencha-touch-2.1.0-commercial/command/sencha.js'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move to the directory of the Sencha SDK which you downloaded:

```
cd /Users/jmc72/Sites/senchaSDK
```

And *then* run the `sencha` command.

**Update**

If you are in the SDK folder, the only other problem you could have would be the SDK Tools version. Uninstall the current version you have and remove it from your path, and then install the latest version from [here](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download).

Comment: Thanks, I tried it before but I am getting exactly the same message.

Comment: @JanuszChudzynski I've updated the post with more information. Perhaps you have a old version of the SDK Tools.

Comment: Thank you,
I am downloading the file from :http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download/sencha-cmd/mac
since I am on the Mac. Hopefully it will work now!

Comment: Thanks! Following the docs I installed SDK Tools v2, but your link revealed that there's this new 'Sencha Cmd' v3. This was the one I needed to have installed to work with the latest SDK 2.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Create a file '.senchasdk' in your project folder and in it simply type sdk and save... In your project folder ensure that your framework files such as sencha-touch.js, debug.js etc are in the sdk folder

Go to command line and type sencha again this time it should work...I faced this problem many times before it is because sencha command looks for a senchasdk hidden file hope it helps...

Comment: I am sorry but I just realized it didn't help me completely...look at my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

That error is because you dont have sencha sdk directory in your project folder...

First create a dummy project using sencha generate app lets say demo...
Go to the demo folder you will find a sdk folder there copy that and put it in your current project folder then try sencha command in your project folder again...

Reason for that error is because when you type sencha command in your project folder it searches for a node.js file inside the sdk folder i think the path is sdk/command/node.js or something(dont remember)... Probably in your current sdk folder the file is not present...